# When should I change next_payment_attempt value using Stripe Invoice API?

Tags: api, stripe-payments, webhooks, invoice

As I understand after Stripe fails to capture payment for an invoice I will be notified via `invoice.payment_failed` webhook event. But when should I specify `next_payment_attempt` for the next payment retry? Is it when invoice is created or when invoice is failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't update `next_payment_attempt`. The settings to control dunning are [in the Stripe Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/billing/automatic) and further discussed [in the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/automatic-collection).